# how can i aply this javascript code to a webpage showed in a iframe html tag?

Tags: javascript, iframe

how can i use this javascript code on a webpage, who is inside an iframe html tag?

```
window.highlight = function() {
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    span.onclick = function (ev) {
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML), this);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
    selection.insertNode(span);
}
```

Comment: In case you didn't realize, if the webpage is from a different domain than your main page, you won't be able to do this.

Comment: should be possible because i found this web app who is made to do something similar, please check this out: http://www.awesomehighlighter.com/

Comment: If you inspect that page, you'll see that they are fetching the iframe content through a proxy, so each frame has the same domain.

Comment: GGG please can you give me some reference who can help me to learn about the process that you are explaining, thanks

Comment: visit that awesomehighlighter link, have it load google.com. Right click the google logo and click inspect. Find the iframe that the google stuff is in. Look at its `src` attribute -- it's being served from awesomehighlighter, not google.

Comment: GGG please tell me how can i do that?, im going to make another question, and if you answer me the points will be yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe is on the same domain as the parent, you can use window.parent.whatever instead of window.whatever, and parent.document.whatever instead of document.whatever.

If the iframe is NOT hosted on the same domain as the parent, then you cannot access it, as this is what is called cross-site-scripting (XSS).

Comment: i have a question; the cross site scripting is illegal?

Comment: It is a security measure built into virtually every browser out there since..forever now.  You can of course alter your own browser to not behave like this, though AFAIK there is no setting to disable it, you'd have to change the source code.  Or you could program your own browser that does not adhere to the standard.  But that obviously only applies to YOUR browser, not everybody else's out there.

Comment: Chrome actually does have a setting to disable it. Start it with `--disable-web-security`. Not sure if moz has anything similar.